# How to find the number of cores in a windows computer using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've been searching for a while but I have not had any luck finding the answer I need. I already know how to use **%OS%** and **%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%**
but I've had no avail. I'm not looking for super complex coding examples, and I know there's one that are just like the ones stated above. *(To be honest, I can't remember the game that had it!)* Anyway. If you guys know it, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

it's a system var:
`%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It helped a ton too. (I knew it was a system variable, as I briefly said in my question, I just couldn't think of what it was.)

Comment: to get a list of all of the system variables, just type in `set`

Comment: That's also extremely helpful. (To be honest, it even displayed some stuff I didn't even know existed so far. Huh.)

Answer (score 0):

in windows: `wmic cpu get NumberOfCores` works for me or in linux: `nproc`

Comment: It does not exactly work if you're not an administrator. But it was a good shot. I did try "%NumberOfCores%" But it failed me. I'm still working on it though.

Comment: ah sorry I hadn't thought of that

Comment: No no it's fine, I'm satisfied with both answers. Both new ways to do something.